# Python playsound() error when i change directory

Tags: python, import, path, desktop, playsound

I've a problem with Playsound and i don't know why... for me it's not understandable...

The code

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound(r"C:\\Users\\Toto\\Desktop\\songs\\dring.mp3")
```

It's work i'm happy, now i copy/paste the same directory (songs\dring.mp3) away from the desk for example my usb device (or other, no matter where i put it)

On my code i change the path

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound(r"D:\\songs\\ding.mp3)
```

i've always this error

Error 259 for command:
the driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.

It's work only my desktop, elsewhere it does not work.. can you help me?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...

you need to uninstall playsound 1.3.0 using :

```
pip uninstall playsound
```

(press `y` to proceed)

Then uninstall the old and pure version of playsound by this command :

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

It worked perfectly for me